# Django frontend app not loading React Component

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

i am following [tranversy Media Django-React tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieYIzvdt2U). After the server is running ok, but the components in my App.js file are not displayed in the index.html. Kindly help on what could be wrong, all.

This is my project tree:
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppomd.png)

**Then my app.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>React App</h1>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**My index.html**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">  

    <title>Lead Manager</title>

    {%load static%}

</head>

<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script>src="{%static "frontend/main.js"%}"</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
import App from './components/App';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader:"babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

The backend is working fine using the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
<script>src="{%static "frontend/main.js"%}"</script>
```

to this

```
<script src="{%static "frontend/main.js"%}"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, cant believe it was such a silly error